# ListView doesnt fire setOnLongClickListener, only setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

I'd like to have both type of clicks on a listView - onClick and LongClick.

I've implemented it like this:

```
this.listViewSub = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listsub);

this.listViewSub.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView parent, final View view, final int position,
                final long id) { ... }    });

        // listen to long click - to share texts
    this.listViewSub.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) { ... } });
```

But it does't fire the Long Click.
Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to enable the `LongClickable`

```
list.setLongClickable(true);
```

and

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3) {

}
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! Solved my problem :)

And BTW - you don't have to do setLongClickable trough code, its nicer when you determn it through the XML:
android:longClickable="true"

Comment: The documentation of `setOnItemLongClickListener` says that "If this view is not long clickable, it becomes long clickable."

Comment: Make sure to use `setOnItemLongClickListener`, **NOT** `setOnLongClickListener`

Answer (score 7):

@Vadim, are your listview's adapter is extends from `BaseAdapter`? if yes, then also need to set           `convertView.setLongClickable(true);` in the `getView()`.

Comment: Why did I have to set `setLongClickable(true)` in `getView()` and `android:longClickable="true"` in **ListView's XML declaration?**

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to set `android:longClickable="true"` in the XML file that contains my ListView **row** layout (not ListView layout) for the item to be long-clickable.

Comment: Of the many proposed solutions I've seen for this issue (and I've tried them ALL), this is the only one that has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

[onLongClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick%28android.view.View%29) returns true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise. So if the event is handled by this method, return true.

Comment: I've added a breakpoint inside this method, and it doesn't stops there.. it looks like it doesnt fire the event.