# LongClickListener on ListView

Tags: android, listview, onlongclicklistener

I have a ListView and want to get the long-click events on the ListView itself, not on the individual items in the ListView. I believe it should be as straight forward as just called `ListView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener)`. However, for me, it seems to do nothing at all. I'm just wondering if anyone else has the same issue with all ListViews or it just me and my implementation of the ListView made this not work.

I referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607479/listview-doesnt-fire-setonlongclicklistener-only-setonitemclicklistener/6607711#6607711) and tried using `ListView.setLongClickable(true)` but it still didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean if you have a ListView that is bigger than it needs to be and someone is LongClicking on a portion of it not occupied by children? Do your list children have LongClick actions themselves?

Comment: Yea, what I mean is when there is nothing in the ListView, the ListView should still be long clickable. Because my main concern right now is that there is no way of long clicking if there is nothing in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to define a separate TextView in the parent layout, with id attribute to be `android:id="@+id/android:empty"` which would be displayed if there are no elements in the ListView, saying something like "--List is empty--", and that being long-clickable. You can easily manipulate the Click for the respective TextView.

In cases where the ListView ought to be long clickable, you can leave a small gap on the parent view, and set the parent view as Long clickable, rather than the ListView.